# Regex pattern to find string after second occurrence

Tags: regex

I have a string like below.

```
#EXTINF:-1  tvg-id=ts191  tvg- 
logo=http://188.155.56.49/jumpstart/Temp_Live/cdn/HLS/Channel/imageContent-795-j5m7axrc- 
v1/imageContent-795-j5m7axrc-m1.png   group-title=Entertainment,   DD National
#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.license_type=com.widevine.alpha 
#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.license_key=https://tatasky.live.ott.irdeto.com/Widevine/getlicense?_session=y249xI2vioV2INEcjlJg4u7JC
https://delta12tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/3569776.mpd
```

I'm looking for regex pattern to find link which is after `licence_key` link. I have tried below pattern but it's giving first link only.

`(?<=#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.license_key=).*`

I just want `https://delta12tatasky.akamaized.net/out/i/3569776.mpd` as result.

Live copy available here [Regexer Link](http://regexr.com/6b02s) to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for getting next line after a given fixed pattern:

```sh
#KODIPROP:inputstream\.adaptive\.license_key=.*\r?\n\K.+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJW98K/1)

If `\K` is not available in your regex flavour then use:

```sh
#KODIPROP:inputstream\.adaptive\.license_key=.*\r?\n(.+)
```

And use capture group #1 for your link.

**RegEx Details:**

- `#KODIPROP:inputstream\.adaptive\.license_key=`: Match this prefix text literally
- `.*\r?\n`: Match any text followed by  line break
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `.+`: Match 1+ of any characters

Comment: You are awesome @anubhava. It's perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Indeed that was the intent. First regex should not have been capture groups (edited)

Comment: You still need a small adjustment in #2. :-)

Comment: Indeed you are right